# Android ConstraintLayout Barrier programmatically not working

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, anko

I'm trying to get a `ConstraintLayout` with a `Barrier` working programmatically. I'm using anko for my code. Everything is working fine, but as soon as I try to use the `Barrier` the view connected to the `Barrier` is set to the top of the view instead of below what I said. Here is the code:

```
    constraintLayout {
        imageView = imageView {
            id = View.generateViewId()
            backgroundColorResource = R.color.black
            scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP
        }.lparamsMargin(width = matchParent, height = imageHeight)

        val gradientView = view {
            id = View.generateViewId()
            background = getGradient(Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.BLACK, 0.5f)
        }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = gradientHeight) {
            bottomToBottom = imageView.id
        }

        titleTextView = textView {
            id = View.generateViewId()
            typeface = context.font(R.font.value_regular)
            textSize = 40f
            textColor = Color.WHITE
            gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            horizontalPadding = Dimensions.mediumViewPadding
        }.lparams(width = matchParent) {
            topToTop = imageView.id
            bottomToBottom = imageView.id
        }

        dateTextView = textView {
            id = View.generateViewId()
            typeface = context.font(R.font.value_regular)
            textSize = 21f
            textColor = Color.WHITE
            gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            horizontalPadding = Dimensions.mediumViewPadding
        }.lparams(width = matchParent) {
            bottomToTop = titleTextView.id
            bottomMargin = Dimensions.smallViewPadding
        }

        subtitleTextView = textView {
            id = View.generateViewId()
            typeface = context.font(R.font.value_regular)
            textSize = 16f
            textColorResource = R.color.textColorOffWhite
            gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            horizontalPadding = Dimensions.mediumViewPadding
        }.lparams(width = matchParent) {
            topToBottom = titleTextView.id
            topMargin = Dimensions.smallViewPadding
        }

        val textGuideline = guideline {
            id = View.generateViewId()
        }.lparams(width = matchParent) {
            topToTop = gradientView.id
            bottomToBottom = gradientView.id
            verticalBias = 0.7f
        }

        val textBarrier = barrier {
            id = View.generateViewId()
            referencedIds = intArrayOf(subtitleTextView.id, textGuideline.id)
            type = Barrier.BOTTOM
        }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent)

        textTextView = textView {
            id = View.generateViewId()
            typeface = context.font(R.font.value_regular)
            textSize = 21f
            textColorResource = R.color.textColorOffWhite
            lineSpacingMult = 1.38f
            gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            horizontalPadding = Dimensions.mediumViewPadding
        }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent) {
            topToBottom = textBarrier.id
        }
    }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent)
```

What I'm trying to do is let the text overlap the image and gradient, unless the title is too big and pushes the text lower. If I put `topToBottom = textGuideline.id` it works like expected, but if the title is too long I want it to push the text lower.

The version of `ConstraintLayout` I'm using is 2.0.0-beta1.

Comment: Any luck solving your problem ? I have the same issue and I think the method `setReferenceIds()` in Barrier doesn't do much. We should be calling `addId()` or `setIds()` but they are private in the base class ConstraintHelper.

Comment: @JDenais Not exactly, I fixed the problem with the view on top. Apparently `barrier` in anko doesn't work. So I'm using `applyConstraintSet` and use this: `createBarrier(barrierId, Barrier.BOTTOM, subtitleTextView.id, textGuideline.id)`. Now it is sort of where it should be. But my problem now is it doesn't respect the `verticalBias` of the `guideline`. So what I know is a view works better than a `guideline` and if you put the barrierId in ids.xml it works better as well, but didn't manage to fully fix the `verticalBias` issue, so still working on that. I'll answer this for other people

Answer (score 0):

`barrier` in anko doesn't work, you have to use `createBarrier` which can be used in `applyConstraintSet`. This will fix your view being on top. But for me it didn't quite work yet. Because my `guideline` uses a `verticalBias` this property is ignored when using a `barrier`. What I've noticed is that instead of `guideline` using `view` with a height of 1 works better and putting the barrierId in ids.xml also works better, but for now I don't use a `verticalBias` and just calculated where the view should be. Here is my code now:

```
            applyConstraintSet {
                gradientView {
                    connect(ConstraintSetBuilder.Side.BOTTOM to ConstraintSetBuilder.Side.BOTTOM of imageView)
                }

                titleTextView {
                    connect(
                        ConstraintSetBuilder.Side.TOP to ConstraintSetBuilder.Side.TOP of imageView,
                        ConstraintSetBuilder.Side.BOTTOM to ConstraintSetBuilder.Side.BOTTOM of imageView
                    )
                }

                dateTextView {
                    connect(ConstraintSetBuilder.Side.BOTTOM to ConstraintSetBuilder.Side.TOP of titleTextView margin Dimensions.smallViewPadding)
                }

                subtitleTextView {
                    connect(ConstraintSetBuilder.Side.TOP to ConstraintSetBuilder.Side.BOTTOM of titleTextView margin Dimensions.smallViewPadding)
                }

                textGuideline {
                    connect(
                        ConstraintSetBuilder.Side.TOP to ConstraintSetBuilder.Side.TOP of gradientView margin (gradientHeight.toFloat() * 0.7f).toInt()
                    )
                }

                val barrierId = View.generateViewId()
                createBarrier(barrierId, Barrier.BOTTOM, subtitleTextView.id, textGuideline.id)

                textTextView {
                    connect(ConstraintSetBuilder.Side.TOP to ConstraintSetBuilder.Side.BOTTOM of barrierId margin Dimensions.mediumViewPadding)
                }
            }
```